# how to attach screenshots in getgauge table

Tags: javascript, getgauge

I need to attach screenshots in the table both in HTML report and markdown file passed from the spec file in getgauge.

I have injected the jQuery to manipulate the HTML DOM.

**Is there any native way to attach screenshots right next to a table row in HTML report? or any way to substitute the path/value with an image?**

### Actual HTML report:

[image]

### Markdown file:

When I convert SPEC file to markdown file.
[image]

### Expected HTML report:

In this screenshot is attached in the table itself.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of custom screenshots. Have look at [docs](https://docs.gauge.org/latest/writing-specifications.html#custom-screenshots-in-reports) for more details.

Comment: @Aproorva, I referred to that document but screenshots are coming at the end of the table but the requirement is to get the screenshot right in the next to a table row or in particular row, column index.